# recent added record not included in CrmOrganizationServiceContext ContactSet

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

When I run the code below it adds the record BUT it doesn't get included in the ContactSet at first. Only if I run it again it shows on the ContactSet, and it shows once, besides the fact that I get the record duplicated. Any idea why the ContactSet doesn't show the new record created?

```
       var xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm");

        //Create a new contact called Allison Brown.
        var testContact = new Contact
        {
            FirstName = "Allison",
            LastName = "Brown",
            Address1_Line1 = "101 W 1st St",
            Address1_City = "Los Angeles",
            Address1_StateOrProvince = "CA",
            Address1_PostalCode = "90001",
            Telephone1 = "310-111-1111",
            EMailAddress1 = "allisonbrown@aol.com"
        };

        xrm.AddObject(testContact);
        xrm.SaveChanges();
        var exampleContacts = xrm.ContactSet.Where(c => c.EMailAddress1.EndsWith(".com"));
        return View(exampleContacts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how the [context tracks records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.mergeoption.aspx).  By default the MergeOption enumeration is set to AppendOnly. This means once a record is being tracked in the context it won't be updated with data from the server.  So when you started tracking testContact it won't let you retrieve it because it considers it a "new" record (without a Guid).  So what you most likely want to do is set the enumeration on the context to be NoTracking or OverwriteChanges.  That way it won't track the record in the context, or update it when you make the call to retrieve the record.